# Changing PATH, HOME env variables of dropbear ssh session

Tags: root-access, ssh

I made a dropbear multi binary that has android patch.
But everytime , when i login via ssh using dropbear as ssh server.
 On checking environment variables, I get ::
HOME=/sdcard
PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin

I found no flag for changing these in dropbear help.

```
-A Android Mode, specify a user explicitly
-N Android Mode, user name
-C Android Mode, password
-R Android Mode, public key file (authorized_keys)
-U Android Mode, UID
-G Android Mode, GID
-b bannerfile   Display the contents of bannerfile before user login
            (default: none)
-d dsskeyfile   Use dsskeyfile for the dss host key
            (default: /data/data/br.com.bott.droidsshd/files/etc/dropbear_dss_host_key)
-r rsakeyfile   Use rsakeyfile for the rsa host key
            (default: /data/data/br.com.bott.droidsshd/files/etc/dropbear_rsa_host_key)
-F              Don't fork into background
-E              Log to stderr rather than syslog
-w              Disallow root logins
-s              Disable password logins
-g              Disable password logins for root
-p [address:]port
            Listen on specified tcp port (and optionally address),
            up to 10 can be specified
            (default port is 2222 if none specified)
-P PidFile      Create pid file PidFile
            (default /data/data/br.com.bott.droidsshd/files/run/dropbear.pid)
-W <receive_window_buffer> (default 24576, larger may be faster, max 1MB)
-K <keepalive>  (0 is never, default 0)
-I <idle_timeout>  (0 is never, default 0)
```

How can I change  default PATH & HOME variables in dropbear ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the default HOME and PATH variables in Dropbear but you could create a symlink to the directories you want.

You don't mention why you need to change the default variables?

Comment: Actually, I have installed binaries in many other folders, that I want to include in PATH.         Dropbear default HOME points to sdcard,  whereas I want to change my HOME directory to folder present in other partition(ext4).             I think , It is possible to change both of them, as QuickSSHd app for android has its own PATH  and HOME, and it uses dropbear.